PWA uses navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice but is failing
I have developed a PWA where I use navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice to get a list of available devices around the phone. On most devices based on Android, this code works very well. But I have one user where no window with the list is displayed. Nothing is displayed. There is no empty list .. there is really nothing .. there is no error in the log.
The PWA ist installed on Android 14 with the latest version of Chrome. The PWA is delivered via HTTPS and the report in Lighthouse was okay.
Update
If I open an other implementation of the same function, there is a windows which asks for permissions to find devices nearby.
I set the permissions for chrome to not find devices nearby and on my phone I get the same prompt and will be asked to set the permission.
But on the faulty device there isnt´t this dialog.

Could you show the code, requestDevice is a Promise, how are you handling errors & success etc.
